# JSP class undefined type after project conversion to maven

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, maven

Im trying to compile this project h__p://ross-warren.co.uk/my-twitter-clone-using-jsp-and-cassandra/

I have downloaded it, and spend almost one day searching for all dependency jar files and still I was not able to run that project. When I did some search I have discover maven. So I've downloaded it, in eclipse I click convert to maven or something, I've added some dependecy records to pom.xml and I still Im not able to run the project. There are some errors in jsp files. These errors werent there befoe.

for example in file **LogChech.jsp**

```
    <jsp:useBean id="User"    
    class="uk.co.ross_warren.litter.stores.UserStore"
    scope="session"
    ></jsp:useBean>
```

I have error **Undefined type: UserStore**.
I dont know where is the problem but I think there is somethign wrong with packages, becase before project conversion I had all java files in packages (at least eclipse showed package icon) and now there is only normal folder icons and folder tree structure with all java files however the first line in java files is package something which is fine I think.

thank you for your help

**EDIT**

this is my pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Cinnamon</groupId>
  <artifactId>Cinnamon</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.4</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.4</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                        <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-4</version>
              </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

This is the first image how it looked like before maven conversion
http://oi39.tinypic.com/2q84o5z.

And this is how it looks like now
http://oi44.tinypic.com/14nmgyf.

ok stack overflow says I cant submit images, so please take that url and add jpg extension to see image

Comment: Can you post the pom you created? The project does not seem to use the standard maven directory layout, did you configure the source directories accordingly?

Comment: I edited my post. I didnt edit my source directories, becasue I dont know how. Im pretty new to eclipse and all java ee stuff. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard maven directory layout expects java sources to be in `src/main/java` and web resources in `src/main/webapp`. So your java sources directly in `src` weren't even compiled. These directories can be configured in the `build` section of your pom.xml. To set the directory for web resources you also have to configure the maven-war-plugin.

**Edit:** It seems you were also missing some dependencies, the pom below compiles without errors on the command line. I'm not an eclipse user myself but this should work in eclipse too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Cinnamon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cinnamon</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <directory>build</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
        <!-- not used in your project -->
        <testSourceDirectory>srcTest</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
            <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.expressme</groupId>
            <artifactId>JOpenId</artifactId>
            <version>1.08</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but its not working. My project looks like this now http://oi44.tinypic.com/2hn2om9.jpg. I have there many errors like "The import org.json cannot be resolved". How do I know what should I put into pom.xml I mean groupId artefactID and version. Another thing how should I compile project maven build or normal build. It looks like maven is not helping me because I have got rid of these errors before by including jar files to classpath. I was able to compile but when I run it there were some errors like something with thirft.

Comment: Would you mind if I send you my eclipse project and you try to fix it ? I would be very glad, but Im also very thankfull for your any of your suggestions

Comment: @Velchester: I added the full pom in my answer, there were also some dependencies on servlet-api, openid, jsoup and json missing.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann thank you very much. It seems it works. I have to set up cassandra database and its going to be ok. Thank you very much once again. It can be compiled, it runs smoothly but cant connect to database. thank you for your help and time